# Ajax doesn't work sometimes

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using Ajax in my web application, and here's my Ajax Jquery function :

```
$(".AlarmLink").click(function(){
            alert('ok');
            $(".page-content").empty();
            $("#alarm-loader").css('display','block');
            $.post($(this).attr("href"),                       
                       function(data){
                        var PageContent = $(data).find(".page-content");
                        $("#alarm-loader").css('display','none');
                        $(".page-content").append(PageContent.html());
                    });
            return false;
    });
```

and I call it from HTML link using the  class="AlarmLink".

But the problem is that this works sometimes and sometimes not .

Comment: Define 'doesn't work sometimes'. Have you checked for errors? Do you get a response every time?

Comment: "this works sometimes" so there is no error

Comment: Q: Did you wrap the code shown in a jQuery document load event?

Comment: Before it should be said as AJAX problem; probably the click even it is not being fired. There could be many reason like - e.prevent..() or event has not been attached. Hence recommendation would be to set console.log and see whenever you click , it actually does call. If number of clicks are not matching with the log entries then the problem is not AJAX.

Comment: Define does not work: you see the alert-box appear, but the ajax fails, or you do not see the alert box at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Probably you have elements added to page after listener is set.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(document).on('click', '.AlarmLink', function() {
   alert('ok');
            $(".page-content").empty();
            $("#alarm-loader").css('display','block');
            $.post($(this).attr("href"),                       
                       function(data){
                        var PageContent = $(data).find(".page-content");
                        $("#alarm-loader").css('display','none');
                        $(".page-content").append(PageContent.html());
                    });
            return false;
  })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

A few possible problems,

- Wrap it in a document ready event (if you do not already)
- Ensure you stop the link click ("I call it from HTML link") from occurring with `e.preventDefault()`, although I see your return false does that (and `e.stopPropagation()`) already. So you do not need both, just `e.preventDefault();` or your `return false`.
- If the element may be changing dynamically, use a delgated version of `on` targetting the document, then filtering by your `.AlarmLink` selector (after the click occurs).

Putting all this together you get:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', ".AlarmLink", function(e){
            alert('ok');
            $(".page-content").empty();
            $("#alarm-loader").css('display','block');
            $.post($(this).attr("href"),                       
                       function(data){
                        var PageContent = $(data).find(".page-content");
                        $("#alarm-loader").css('display','none');
                        $(".page-content").append(PageContent.html());
                    });
            return false;
    });
});
```

### Note:

A DOM ready handler is not required for a delegated event attached to `document` as `document` always exists, so you can reduce the example to:

```
$(document).on('click', ".AlarmLink", function(e){
        alert('ok');
        $(".page-content").empty();
        $("#alarm-loader").css('display','block');
        $.post($(this).attr("href"),                       
                   function(data){
                    var PageContent = $(data).find(".page-content");
                    $("#alarm-loader").css('display','none');
                    $(".page-content").append(PageContent.html());
                });
        return false;
});
```

Comment: Just so it won't throw other people off if they come to this question, it's `e.preventDefault();`. ****

Comment: @Ale: Cheers for the typo fix :) That line is redundant as it happens as `return false` does that and `e.stopPropagation()`. Removed extra line

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, It will help you most probably

```
   $(function(){
    $(".AlarmLink").click(function(){
                alert('ok');
                $(".page-content").empty();
                $("#alarm-loader").css('display','block');
                $.post($(this).attr("href"),                       
                           function(data){
                            var PageContent = $(data).find(".page-content");
                            $("#alarm-loader").css('display','none');
                            $(".page-content").append(PageContent.html());
                        });
                return false;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".AlarmLink").live('click', function() {

        alert('ok');

        $(".page-content").empty();
        $("#alarm-loader").css('display','block');
        $.post($(this).attr("href"),                       
                   function(data){
                    var PageContent = $(data).find(".page-content");
                    $("#alarm-loader").css('display','none');
                    $(".page-content").append(PageContent.html());
                });
        return false;
    })
});
```